# What is the access for a display name I'm given when invoking an action?

Tags: actions-on-google

When creating my action I'm asked to use a display name for the invoking of the action on the assistant:

*Display name is publicly displayed in the Actions directory. Users say or type the display name to begin interacting with your Actions. For example, if the display name is Dr. Music, users can say "Hey Google, Talk to Dr. Music", or type "Talk to Dr. Music" to invoke the Actions.*

What I'm a little confused about is in order for the user to invoke my action do they have to say "Talk to xxx"? Or are they allowed to say what's is used for the 'display name'? I see some actions use a name or command and others use the "Talk to".

An example is if my display name is "food store" as an registered app or company can I have the user say "order 20 carrots from **food store**" or does it have to be "Talk to **food store**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Actions will be able to be invoked using "Talk to *display name*". This is like going to the URL of a website directly. This is known as [explicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit).

You can also make your Action explicitly invokable with additional parameters, so you can say something like "Ask *display name* to order 20 carrots". These are [invocation phrases](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit#invocation_phrase_optional). This is like going to the URL of a website, but being able to directly type in a path on the site.

In some cases, if a user asks the Assistant a question, or asks it to do something, the Assistant may identify an Action that can do that. This is something like doing a Google search on a question, and Google either providing a link to a website or providing a portion of the site in the sidebar of the answers. This is known as [implicit invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/implicit), and while it may work, it is not guaranteed that it works for any specific invocation. In general, your action can suggest phrases that will work, and the more specific those phrases are, the better chance they have of being accepted.

You may also register your Action to handle specific [built-in intents](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/built-in-intents). These are phrases that have already been crafted to meet user requests, and that the Assistant will know to pass off to you, since you can handle the request. You can think of them as being similar to smart home requests for other activities. There are a limited number of these intents, but if you have an action that fits the category, it makes sense to support it.